# Azure Application Insights - Using Custom Dimensions and Custom Measurements in Custom Events from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a single page application written with JavaScript. I am currently logging events to Azure Application Insights using the [JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics). At this time, I am logging events using code that looks like this:

```
let eventLog = {
  name: 'Custom Event Name',
  customDimensions: {
    target: 'app'
  },
  customMeasurements: {
    totalTime: '00:00:01.1234'
  }
};

appInsights.trackEvent(eventLog);
```

When I run my code, I notice that custom events are being written to my Application Insights instance. While the correct event name is shown in Application Insights, I do not see any custom dimensions or custom measurements.

How do I log custom dimensions and custom measurements with custom events to Azure Application Insights via the JavaScript API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field names of the telemetry object should be `properties` and `measurements` respectively in code as below. Also, value of measurements items should be number.

```js
let eventLog = {
  name: 'Custom Event Name',
  properties: {
    target: 'app'
  },
  measurements: {
    totalTime: 0.34567
  }
};

appInsights.trackEvent(eventLog);
```

[image]

Comment: How do you query these values then?

Comment: @LOST - customEvents | where customDimensions.target == "app".  Alternately, in the screenshot above, if you expand the node you want (e.g. customDimensions), you can right click on the specific child element you want to query and click "Include" (or "Exclude" depending on how you want to filter) and it will write the syntax for you (helpful for nested elements so you dont have to do the "parse_json(tostring(parse_json..." yourself